# Karma "not found" error when testing angularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, netbeans

I want to test my AngularJS application in Netbeans IDE, and I think I have configured the files correctly; But this error shows up when I right click on my project and click Test:

```
Karma cannot start (incorrect Karma set?), review IDE log for details
```

Could anyone please help me where is wrong? Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

The karma.cmd file is inside this folder:

C:\MyProject\node_modules.bin